# Materialized path relationship in declarative SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, declarative, materialized-path-pattern

I have a hierarchical categories model, where hierarchy is maintained using materialized path (one character per level):

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id = Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    path = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)

    # problematic relationship
    all_subcats = relationship('Category', lazy='dynamic', viewonly=True,
                               primaryjoin=foreign(path).like(remote(path).concat('%')))
```

When trying to define "all subcategories" relationship I run into a problem:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't determine relationship direction for
relationship 'Category.all_subcats' - foreign key columns within the join
condition are present in both the parent and the child's mapped tables.
Ensure that only those columns referring to a parent column are marked as
foreign, either via the foreign() annotation or via the foreign_keys argument.
```

SQLAlchemy is confused, because I'm joining on the *same column*. All examples I've managed to find always join on different columns.

Is this sort of relationship possible at all? I want to query through this join, so custom @property is not acceptable.

Comment: you should report issues like these on the [sqlalchemy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlalchemy).  I'm testing a patch for this now.

Comment: wow this is really wacky.   need to see if i can commit this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latest git master or version 0.9.5 or greater of SQLAlchemy.  Then:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'element'

    path = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    related = relationship('Element',
                           primaryjoin=
                                remote(foreign(path)).like(
                                        path.concat('/%')),
                           viewonly=True,
                           order_by=path)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)
sess.add_all([
    Element(path="/foo"),
    Element(path="/foo/bar1"),
    Element(path="/foo/bar2"),
    Element(path="/foo/bar2/bat1"),
    Element(path="/foo/bar2/bat2"),
    Element(path="/foo/bar3"),
    Element(path="/bar"),
    Element(path="/bar/bat1")
])

e1 = sess.query(Element).filter_by(path="/foo/bar2").first()
print [e.path for e in e1.related]
```

note that this model, whether you deal with "descendants" or "anscestors", uses collections.  You want to keep `remote()` and `foreign()` together so that the ORM considers it as one to many.

Comment: It works just fine with the SQLAlchemy git master. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to do subquery eager loading with this, without issuing a separate SELECT for each object?

Comment: what happens if you use subqueryload()?  it fails?   might need some more fixes in that case, post a bug report.

Comment: @zzzeek Hm, it seems `subqueryload()` works but specifying `lazy="subquery"` does not. I'll file a bug report.